# web scraping how to save unavalible data as a null

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

hi i am trying to get data with web scraping but my code gets untill **"old_price" = null**  how can i skip this data  if it is empty or **how can i read it and save unavailable as a null**
this is my python code

```
  import requests
  import json
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
  header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
  
  base_url = "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlar"
  
  r = requests.get(base_url,headers=header)
  
  if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    books = soup.find_all('li',attrs={"class":"column"})
  
    result=[]
    for book in books:
    title=book.find('h3').text.strip()
    link=base_url +book.find('a')['href']
    picture = base_url + book.find('img')['src']
    first_price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'newPrice'}).find('ins').text[:10].strip().strip()+" TL"
    old_price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'oldPrice'}).find('del').text.strip()
    single ={'title':title,'link':link,'picture':picture,'first_price':first_price,'old_price':old_price}
    result.append(single)
    with open('book.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(result ,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
  else:
     print(r.status_code)
```

```html
<div class="proDetail">
  <a href="https://test.com"class="oldPrice" title="Premium">           
      <del>69,00 TL</del></a>          
  <a href="https://test.com"class="newPrice" title="Premium">         
     <ins>14,90</ins>           
         </a> 
  <a href="https://test.com"class="newPrice" title="Premium">         
     <ins>19,90</ins>           
  </a>
</div>
     <a href="https://test.com"class="oldPrice" title="Premium">                
      <del>79,00 TL</del></a>          
  <a href="https://test.com"class="newPrice" title="Premium">         
     <ins>34,90</ins>           
         </a>
```

and this is my error

```
   File "C:\Users\Red\Desktop\webcrawler-tutorial-master\hepsiburada\main.py", line 22, in <module>
 old_price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'oldPrice'}).find('del').text.strip()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good practice in scraping for the name, Price, links we need to have a good error handling for each of the fields we're scraping. Something like below

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}

base_url = "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlar"

r = requests.get(base_url,headers=header)

if r.status_code == 200:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  books = soup.find_all('li',attrs={"class":"column"})

  result=[]
  for book in books:
    title=book.find('h3').text.strip()
    link=base_url +book.find('a')['href']
    picture = base_url + book.find('img')['src']
    first_price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'newPrice'}).find('ins').text[:10].strip().strip()+" TL"
    if book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'oldPrice'}):
       old_price = book.find('a', attrs={'class': 'oldPrice'}).find('del').get_text(strip=True)
    single ={'title':title,'link':link,'picture':picture,'first_price':first_price,'old_price':old_price}
    result.append(single)
    with open('book.json','w') as f:
      json.dump(result ,f,indent=4)
else:
   print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir I've corrected the code snippet. Basically, if you look at the iterable object items that you've on the page doesn't have an old price for certain items and earlier we were having logic to check the old price and find('del') which is throwing an exception. 
likewise there can be a cases where this same situation can arise for other values as well. you might need to have this error handling for the other value that you're collecting as well